# Is it possible to embed only a single visual from a Shiny App on a website?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to only embed specific visuals (i.e. outputs) from a Shiny App at different locations of a website, while excluding the rest of the UI elements from the Shiny App. The input data would be filtered using URL parameters in the iframe `src` argument (e.g. `<iframe src="https://example.shinyapps.io/shinyappexample/?dataset=titanic" height="400" width="100%"> </iframe>`).

For example, I'd like to only embed the table under the "View" tab in the following Shiny App on my website, using an iframe: https://shiny.posit.co/r/gallery/education/radiant/.

The resulting output inside the iframe on my website would thus look like this (no sidebar/navbar/tabsetpanel):

[image: table_example]

Is there a way to do this?